# Auto connect and reconnect to VPN on Debian 8

Tags: debian, openvpn, vpn

I am searching for a way to always enforce a VPN connection with a chosen profile (ovpn or network manager) whenever I use an internet connection. I want to use OpenVPN and Debian 8.

Is there a package or a nice script that does this?

Have I missed some possible configuration within OpenVPN or another utility to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a simple solution. It works perfect on ethernet or wifi and it even restores the connection on a disconnect.

At first you have to set up a vpn connection with your networkmanger.
After that you have to place a file, i named it `vpnautoconnect` in the `/etc/network/if-up.d` directory. Do not forget to replace `PrivateVPN` with the Name of your VPN-Connection you created before.

```
#!/bin/sh
# vpnautoconnect-script
# Place this file in /etc/network/if-up.d
# Set the ovpn-confgiuration by name
# nmcli con up id <ovpn-name>
nmcli con up id PrivateVPN
```

If you're having problems with this not working, try running `ifup --all -v`, it should show you any error messages related to the startup script. In case it shows you the following message:

```
A password is required to connect to 'PrivateVPN'.
```

All you need to do is click on the icon on the right hand side of the password field and select `Store the password for all users`, which will allow nmcli to use the password.

Answer (score 0):

`vpnautoconnect` can do it.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/vpnautoconnect/

Description :
`vpnautoconnect` is a daemon that allow you to reconnect automatically (at startup too) a vpn create with network manager.It can reconnect very quickly and monitor the bandwith, It works with pptp and openvpn connection.